# Modify GetQueryNameValuePairs() for UrlHelper.Link in ASP.NET WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, query-string

With ASP.NET WebApi, when I send GET `api/question?page=0&name=qwerty&other=params` and API should give result within pagination envelop.

For that, I'd like to put result and change given `page` querystring to other values.

I tried as below code but I got a bad feeling about this.

```
protected HttpResponseMessage CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode httpStatusCode, IEnumerable<Question> entityToEmbed)

    // get QueryString and modify page property
    var dic = new HttpRouteValueDictionary(Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs());
    if (dic.ContainsKey("page"))
        dic["page"] = (page + 1).ToString();
    else
        dic.Add("page", (page + 1).ToString());

    var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(Request);
    var nextLink= page > 0 ? urlHelper.Link("DefaultApi", dic) : null;

    // put it in the envelope
    var pageEnvelope = new PageEnvelope<Question>
        {
            NextPageLink = nextLink,
            Results = entityToEmbed
        };

        HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse<PageEnvelope<Question>>(httpStatusCode, pageEnvelope, this.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter);
        return response;
    }
```

The NextPageLink gives a lot complex result.:
     `http://localhost/api/Question?Length=1&LongLength=1&Rank=1&SyncRoot=System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair%602%5BSystem.String%2CSystem.String%5D%5B%5D&IsReadOnly=False&IsFixedSize=True&IsSynchronized=False&page=1`

My question is,

1. My page handling with `Dictionary` approach seems dirty and wrong. Is there better way to address my problem?
2. I don't know why `urlHelper.Link(routeName, dic)` gives such a verbose ToString result. How to get rid of unusable Dictionary-related properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key issue probably in your code is the conversion to the HttpRouteValueDictionary. New it up instead and add in a loop all key value pairs.

The approach can be simplified quite a lot, and you should also probably want to consider using an HttpActionResult (so that you can more easily test your actions.

You should also avoid using the `httproutevaluedictionary` and instead write your UrlHelper like

```
urlHelper.Link("DefaultApi", new { page = pageNo }) // assuming you just want the page no, or go with the copying approach otherwise.
```

Where just pre calculate your page no (and avoid ToString);

Write it all in an IHttpActionResult that exposes an `int` property with the page No. so you can easily test the action result independently of how you figure out the pagination.

So something like:

```
public class QuestionsResult : IHttpActionResult
{
    public QuestionResult(IEnumerable<Question> questions>, int? nextPage)
    {
       /// set the properties here
    }

    public IEnumerable<Question> Questions { get; private set; }

    public int? NextPage { get; private set; }

    /// ... execution goes here

}
```

To just get the page no, do something like:

Source - http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/releases/whats-new-in-aspnet-web-api-21

```
string page = request.Uri.ParseQueryString()["page"];
```

or

you can use this extension method below (from Rick Strahl)

```
public static string GetQueryString(this HttpRequestMessage request, string key)
{      
    // IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>> - right!
    var queryStrings = request.GetQueryNameValuePairs();
    if (queryStrings == null)
        return null;

    var match = queryStrings.FirstOrDefault(kv => string.Compare(kv.Key, key, true) == 0);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(match.Value))
        return null;

    return match.Value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I now completely utilize `IHttpActionResult` :)